# Question about delta method and variance-stabilization

Tags: data-transformation, poisson-distribution, delta-method, taylor-series

The delta method or variance-stabilizing transformation can be applied to make the variance be "nearly constant" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation). They use the Poisson distribution as an example and argue that the transformation $x \mapsto \sqrt x$ is such a function. They appeal to using a first-order Taylor series approximation of a transformation $Y = g(X)$ which results in $\sigma^2_Y \approx \sigma_X^2 g'(\mu_X)^2$ where $\mu,\sigma^2$ is the mean and variance, respectively.

My question, why did they stop at first order? Indeed, squaring and taking expectation of $g(x) = g(\mu_X) + (x - \mu) g'(\mu_X) + \frac{1}{2} (x - \mu)^2 g''(\mu_X)$ leads to $E[g(x)^2] = g(\mu_X)^2 + \sigma^2 ((g')^2 + gg'') + O((x-\mu)^3)$.

Noting that $(g')^2 + g g'' = (gg')'$, it is clear that a transformation that removes this term entirely is $g(x) = C \sqrt x$. Why can we neglect this second order term that seems to be relevant in terms of magnitude (especially since it cancels the term typically included).

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Why carry out the more complex calculations (to higher order) in the first place?  What do you gain?

Comment: You haven't really addressed the question. The question is why is the second-order term neglected when it seems to not only be the same magnitude, but precisely cancel in the case of the Poisson distribution. Often series approximations are truncated on the basis that higher order terms can be neglected. This seems to not be the case here.

Comment: I'm not trying to address the question--I'm trying to understand it.  I see you write an expression for the raw second moment of $g(x),$ but that's not part of this method, which is based on the *central* second moment. Your question also seems to focus on a special property of the Poisson distribution, whereas this is a general method.  I'm puzzled by what you are trying to get at.

Comment: I'm concerned that this method is based on taking a linear expansion - valid, provided that higher order terms can be neglected. But truthfully it only seems you can neglect this other term if $(g')^2 \gg g g''$ otherwise that term isn't really a "higher" order term. What I am trying to point out, I guess not really clearly is that this other term is ALSO a second order central moment term.

Comment: The problem is that when you expand the terms for the *central* second moment, no such terms appear.

Comment: @Gregory please check the second moment of $Y=g(x)$. This should be $\mathbb{E}[(g(x)-\mathbb{E}[g(x)])^2]$, where $\mathbb{E}[g(x)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[g(x)^2]$ come from the Taylor expansion of $g(x)$ and $g(x)^2$ at the second order.